# How to disable RabbitMQ default tcp listening port - 5672

Tags: rabbitmq

I have configured the RabbitMQ `rabbitmq.config` file with new port number i.e. 5671 with SSL.

Now I want to disable the default port i.e. 5672.

**Config file as below :-**

```
[
  {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/ay/app/xxx/softwares/rabbitmq_server-3.1.1/etc/ssl/cacert.pem"},
                    {certfile,"/ay/app/xxx/softwares/rabbitmq_server-3.1.1/etc/ssl/cert.pem"},
                    {keyfile,"/ay/app/xxx/softwares/rabbitmq_server-3.1.1/etc/ssl/key.pem"},
                    {verify,verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false},

                   {ciphers,[{dhe_rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha},
 {dhe_dss,aes_256_cbc,sha},
 {rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha}]}

                    ]

    }
   ]}
].
```

Now its working on both port 5671 and 5672.But I need to disable the port 5672.
Give some comments or suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix numbers of ports in question. 572 -> 5672 and etc

Comment: Be arware that the option `fail_if_no_peer_cert, false` still allows clients without a certificate to connect. Read more [here](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-bugs/2015-March/004812.html) for information on the `fail_if_no_peer_cert` setting...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To disable standart RabbitMQ 5672 port add `{tcp_listeners, []}` to your rabbitmq.conf:

```
[
  {rabbit, [
     {tcp_listeners, []},
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/ay/app/xxx/softwares/rabbitmq_server-3.1.1/etc/ssl/cacert.pem"},
                    {certfile,"/ay/app/xxx/softwares/rabbitmq_server-3.1.1/etc/ssl/cert.pem"},
                    {keyfile,"/ay/app/xxx/softwares/rabbitmq_server-3.1.1/etc/ssl/key.pem"},
                    {verify,verify_peer},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false},

                   {ciphers,[{dhe_rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha},
 {dhe_dss,aes_256_cbc,sha},
 {rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha}]}

                    ]

    }
   ]}
].
```

It works with RabbitMQ 3.1.5

Answer (score 6):

It appears that to disable non-ssl listening with the new file format, you can do the following:

```
listeners.tcp  = none
```

This has the same effect as the other 3.7 answer, but removes the need to do it in the advanced.config.

Comment: I didn't work for me in rabbitmq-server-3.8. Have you had a chance to test this setting in 3.8?

Comment: @mrc02_kr That's the documentation recommended way, https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#single-stack-ipv4. Seems to have worked for me with 3.8.11.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to do it with the [new configuration file format introduced in RabbitMQ 3.7](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file-formats):

1. [Set up the SSL listener](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) in rabbitmq.conf:

   ```
   listeners.ssl.1 = 5671
   ssl_options.cacertfile = /path/to/testca/cacert.pem
   ssl_options.certfile = /path/to/server/cert.pem
   ssl_options.keyfile = /path/to/server/key.pem
   ssl_options.verify = verify_peer
   ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
   ```
2. [Disable the non-SSL listener](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html)  in advanced.config:

   ```
   [
    {rabbit,
     [{tcp_listeners, []}
     ]}
   ].
   ```

Comment: Is it significant whether advanced.config is used for the second part, instead of rabbitmq.conf?

Comment: I tried a few things to get it working in rabbitmq.conf (not [rabbitmq.config](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file-formats)) but didn't have any luck. Feel free to edit my answer if you get it working!

Comment: From rabbitmq documentation: `Some configuration settings are not possible or are difficult to configure using the sysctl format. As such, it is possible to use an additional config file in the Erlang term format (same as rabbitmq.config). That file is commonly named advanced.config. It will be merged with the configuration provided in rabbitmq.conf.` I guess this is why up to date...