# 'fail_if_no_peer_cert' not working as expected in rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am trying to validate the SSL connection between client and server.
I have two python scripts send.py for producer and receive.py for consumer.
I am using below code to make connection.

```
import pika
ssl_option = {'certfile': '/home/rmqca/client1/cert.pem', 'keyfile': '/home/rmqca/client1/key.pem'}
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost', port=5671, ssl=True, ssl_options=ssl_option)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
```

ALso, in my rabbitmq.config, I am using the below parameters:

```
{ssl_listeners, [5671]},
{ssl_options, [{cacertfile,           "/home/rmqca/testca/cacert.pem"},
           {certfile,             "/home/rmqca/server/cert.pem"},
           {keyfile,              "/home/rmqca/server/key.pem"},
           {verify,               verify_peer},
           {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}]}
```

This works fine when I try connecting through SSL.

But As I wanted to cover negative usecase, like if I make connection without ssl, like using code:

```
import pika  
connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
```

then, as per my understanding, my client should not be able to connect to server. But currently it is connecting fine. I am not sure why this is happening. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Please throw some light here!!!

Comment: I found the answer. By default it listens with TCP in the negative case I mentioned here. Hence the solution is to disable TCP port. The solution is provided here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806313/how-to-disable-rabbitmq-default-tcp-listening-port-5672